# Serialize ids when saving emberjs model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, serialization, ember.js, ember-data

I have an **emberjs** application backed by a nodejs server and **mongodb**. Currently my database is sending documents with an **'_id'** field. I have the followign code to force Ember to **treat '_id' as the primary key**:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
   primaryKey: '_id'
});
```

On the other hand i have two models related by a 'hasMany' relationship as such:

```
App.Player = DS.Model.extend({
 name: DS.attr('string'),
 thumbLink: DS.attr('string'),
 activeGame: DS.belongsTo('game', { async: true }),
 email: DS.attr('string'),
 firstName: DS.attr('string'),
 lastName: DS.attr('string'),
 admin: DS.attr('boolean')
});

App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  active: DS.attr('boolean'),
  players: DS.hasMany('player', { async: true })
});
```

The problem is that when i try to **save the model** ( `this.get('model').save()` )on my controller the ids are not serialized and the result is ember sending the following:

```
{"game":{"name":"Indie/Rock","active":false,"players":[],"_id":"53cbbf43daa978983ee0b101"}}
```

As you can see the players array is **empty**, and as a result, the server is saving that empty array which in fact is not correct. I am aware that it is possible to use `{ embedded: true }` on the models and return the models with embedded documents from the server, but i want to preserve the **async** feature.

I have tried to extend the **game serializer** from `EmbeddedRecordsMixing` as the following:

```
App.GameSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer
                   .extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin)
                   .extend({
                     attrs: {
                       players: {serialize: 'ids', deserialize: 'ids'},
                     }
                   });
```

But when i do so i get the following error from ember even though the ApplicationSerializer is suppossedly telling Ember to user _id as primary key:

```
Assertion Failed: Error: Assertion Failed: You must include an `id` for App.Game in a hash passed to `push`
```

My question is if it is possible to maintain the **async** features of ember-data while being able to serialize the document with the **ids** on it's relation and using _id as a primary key.

Thank you.

Comment: Also mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125334/ember-js-quiz-questions-save-delete-hasmany-data/24130793#24130793

Answer (score 3):

Ember Data is stupid in this aspect, if it's a ManyToOne relationship, it only includes the id from the `belongsTo` side.  Honestly I've had it on my bucket list to submit a PR, but time is limited.

https://github.com/emberjs/data/commit/7f752ad15eb9b9454e3da3f4e0b8c487cdc70ff0#commitcomment-4923439

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

 serializeHasMany: function(record, json, relationship) {
    var key = relationship.key;
    var payloadKey = this.keyForRelationship ? this.keyForRelationship(key, "hasMany") : key;
    var relationshipType = RelationshipChange.determineRelationshipType(record.constructor, relationship);

    if (relationshipType === 'manyToNone' || relationshipType === 'manyToMany'
        || relationshipType === 'manyToOne') {  // This is the change
      json[payloadKey] = get(record, key).mapBy('id');
      // TODO support for polymorphic manyToNone and manyToMany relationships
    }
  },
});
```

Comment: I already have that code on my app, but it does not solve the problem. If i do a console.log(record) and console.log(json) inside the serializeHasMany method the players array is empty although the data coming from the sever on the /api/games call has the players array filled...

Comment: I'm saying that code removes the array on save.  It only saves from the belongsTo side.

Comment: Ok, i misunderstood you, anyway still no solution, right?

Comment: Correct, the current implementation of Ember Data doesn't support it without overriding the `serializeHasMany` (I'll show an example)